# Python: install dash_table_experiments with conda

Tags: python, conda

I've started learning Dash framework, installed `dash_core_components` and the `dash_html_components` libraries using conda without any issues using the following commands

```
conda install -c conda-forge dash-html-components   
conda install -c conda-forge dash-core-components
```

but I cannot install `dash_table_experiments` using conda. There isn't anything on anaconda.org website.

Is pip the only way to install dash_table_experiments?

Answer (score 1):

pip install dash-table-experiments

The only way i found.